# Replacing string with variable in Jenkinsfile using SED command

Tags: sed, continuous-integration, escaping, jenkins-pipeline, jenkins-groovy

I have a Jenkinsfile in which I am fetching a value from AWS console ; and storing in a variable my_es_host , and there is a parameter in my `terraform.tfvars` file i.e. `es_host=""`. I am trying to insert the value of variable my_es_host in the terraform file. Below is the sed command I am using in the Jenkinsfile:

```
sh 'sed -i "s/es_host=\"\"/es_host=\"$my_es_host\"/g" terraform.tfvars
```

This is working as expected in Linux terminal. However, this sed command does not work in a Jenkinsfile. Can someone help me on this please ?

Comment: What is the result? Is anything substituted? Are you sure that $my_es_host is properly available for the sed command? You might want to do `sh 'echo $my_es_host'` beforehand to verify the value.

Comment: Thanks @raspy for looking into it. It runs without an error, but nothing gets substituted in the Jenkinsfile, it works fine on the Linux terminal. sh 'echo $my_es_host' does return the correct value.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe that nothing is substituted, because it may not match the pattern. Jenkins itself will consume one quoting backslash, so you need to double them, e.g.:

```
pipeline {
    agent any
    environment {
        my_es_host = 'whatever'
    }
    stages {
        stage('sed') {
            steps {
                sh 'echo es_host=\\"\\" > terraform.tfvars'
                sh 'cat terraform.tfvars'
                sh 'sed -i "s/es_host=\\"\\"/es_host=\\"$my_es_host\\"/g" terraform.tfvars'
                sh 'cat terraform.tfvars'
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Output:

```
[Pipeline] sh
+ echo es_host=""
[Pipeline] sh
+ cat terraform.tfvars
es_host=""
[Pipeline] sh
+ sed -i s/es_host=""/es_host="whatever"/g terraform.tfvars
[Pipeline] sh
+ cat terraform.tfvars
es_host="whatever"
```

Comment: Thank you ! Let me make the changes.

Comment: Thank you so much @raspy. This works fine if I set the variable in the environment block as suggested by you. However, it does not seem to work when I fetch the value inside a step and use the sed command. This is how my stage looks at present :

Comment: stage('fetch_es_domain'){
steps{
sh 'pwd'
withAWS(role: "es-role", region: "eu-west-1", roleAccount: "XXXXXXXXX"){
dir("/home/jenkins/workspace/alert/dev/"){
sh 'echo "Fetching ES Domain details from aws"'
sh 'aws es describe-elasticsearch-domains --domain-name es-host-log > ./es_host.txt'
sh 'my_es_host=$(cat ./es_host.txt | grep [E]ndpoint | awk -F\': "\' \'{print \$2}\' | awk -F\'"\' \'{print \$1}\')'
sh 'echo $my_es_host'
sh 'cat ./terraform.tfvars'
sh 'sed -i "s/es_host=\\"\\"/es_host=\\"$my_es_host\\"/g" terraform.tfvars'
sh 'cat ./terraform.tfvars'
 
}
}
}
}

Comment: The terraform.tfvars file still somehow happens to be :                                [Pipeline] sh
+ sed -i 's/es_host=""/es_host=""/g' terraform.tfvars
[Pipeline] sh . Can you please provide some pointers.

Comment: The `$my_es_host` variable is local to the shell that you run it in, I believe your `sh 'echo $my_es_host'` also shows it empty. In such case you would probably need to run it in a single shell, i.e.:
`sh 'my_es_host=$(cat ./es_host.txt | grep [E]ndpoint | awk -F\': "\' \'{print \$2}\' | awk -F\'"\' \'{print \$1}\'); sed -i "s/es_host=\\"\\"/es_host=\\"$my_es_host\\"/g" terraform.tfvars'`

Answer (score 0):

Another way to do that is using [HCLQ](https://github.com/mattolenik/hclq) (command line tool for querying and manipulating HashiCorp HCL) here are some examples

```
cat terraform.tfvars | hclq set 'es_host' $my_es_host | tee terraform.tfvars
```

or you can get this value

```
cat terraform.tfvars | hclq get 'es_host'
```